# Getting compilation error on Collections.addAll

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("1");
    a.add("2");
    a.add("3");
    List<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    Collections.addAll(v,a);

     System.out.println(v);

  }
}
```

Error:
/home/compilerauto/sessions/141/MyClass.java:10: addAll(java.util.Collection,T...) in java.util.Collections cannot be applied to (java.util.List,java.util.List)

Why so?

Comment: Because that's not how you use `Collections.addAll()`. Doesn't your IDE tell you that? (You're using an IDE, right?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method signature of addAll is:

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements)
```

as opposed to

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, Collection<? super T> elements)
```

Since `T... elements` can be represented as `T[] elements`, try:

```
Collections.addAll(v,a.toArray());
```

Or use the List interface's addAll:

```
v.addAll(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

[That form of `addAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) doesn't take two `Collection`s, it takes one `Collection` and then multiple items of the same type in that collection to be added to it.

You just want [`v.addAll(a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29), the instance method on the `Collection` itself.